# ASP.NET Templated User Controls "Container" keyword

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm working with Templated User Control's.  In the final markup of the control, the data is being accessed by the *Container* keyword.  I'm using the word 'keyword' freely, because I do not understand whether this is a keyword, or where the Container word is coming from.  Below is an example from my book.

```
//Address User Control markup
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="AddressUcTemplated.ascx.cs" Inherits="AddressUcTemplated" %>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server"
ID="PlaceHolderAddressTemplate">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

--

```
//Address User Control code-behind
public partial class AddressUcTemplated :
System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//clear the controls from the placeholder
PlaceHolderAddressTemplate.Controls.Clear();
if (LayoutTemplate == null)
{
PlaceHolderAddressTemplate.Controls.Add(
new LiteralControl("No template defined."));
}
else
{
AddressUcContainer container = new
AddressUcContainer(this.Address);
this.LayoutTemplate.InstantiateIn(container);
//add the controls to the placeholder
PlaceHolderAddressTemplate.Controls.Add(container);
}
}
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
[TemplateContainer(typeof(AddressUcContainer))]
public ITemplate LayoutTemplate { get; set; }
public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

--

```
//Naming Container Class
    public class AddressUcContainer : Control, INamingContainer
    {
    public AddressUcContainer(Address address)
    {
    this.Address = address;
    }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

--

```
     //Page using the user control; the Container keyword is confusing me in the below //statement
...
<%@ Register src="AddressUcTemplated.ascx" tagname="AddressUcTemplated"
tagprefix="uc1" %>
        <uc1:AddressUcTemplated ID="AddressUcTemplated1"
        runat="server" AddressType="Home">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <h1>Edit Home Address</h1>
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Address Line 1:</td>
        <td>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxAddress" runat="server"
        Text="<%#Container.Address.AddressLine1%>"></asp:TextBox>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

My example code is as follows:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItem %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Intellisense states that Container is a *field/variable* of type `RepeaterItem`. The variable-part tells me that this is some special parsing, since it would most probably been a property if it was public stuff.

Anyway, my code is parsed into, amongst other, the following databinding code:

```
public void __DataBind__control4(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var target = (DataBoundLiteralControl)sender;
    var Container = (RepeaterItem)target.BindingContainer;
    target.SetDataBoundString(0, Convert.ToString(Container.DataItem, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
}
```

`<%# ... %>` is a DataBoundLiteralControl, and `Container` is the variable that's exposed to intellisense. This also shows that there's a `target` variable, which does *not* show up in intellisense, but compiles without any problems. Note that this also gives you access to everything private in the generated class, like `__fileDependencies`.

`<%# target %>` works, while `<%# dummy %>` doesn't. And while at it, `<%# __DataBind__control4(null, null) %>` creates two compilation errors, 1) "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToString(object, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments" and 2) "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'void' to 'object'".

This looks like a simple case of whatever is written between `<%# ... %>` is placed in `Convert.ToString(..., CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)`. It's probably more advanced, involving different ControlBuilders, TemplateParsers, and an ounce of magic, but I think my abstraction works well enough to understand this.